# How to mock up Date object?

Tags: coffeescript, jasmine

I'm trying to write jasmine test for this method

```
currentTime: ->
  Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000)
```

In the test trying this:

```
@date = new Date()
@date = Date(@date.getTime() + 70)
spyOn(window, "Date").andCallFake ->
  @date
expect(@user.currentTime()).toEqual xxx
```

I tried `@date = new Date(@date.getTime() + 70)` but I didn't help.

But I got error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getTime'
```

Any idea how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: `Date(@date.getTime() + 70)` returns a string. Try `new Date`. (Although if that were your whole problem, it should have been `[object String]`…) Also, why are you writing this test that seems needs more testing then what it’s written to test?

Comment: @minitech, I've tried it already with the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mock the Date constructor so that he returns a mock for `getTime` that returns always the same int:

```
spyOn(window, "Date").andReturn {getTime: -> 1000}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was taken from [here](http://massalabs.com/Presentations/slides/rails_fast_tests.html#slide-9)

```
@_Date = Date
testContext = @
time = new Date().getTime() + 400
spyOn(window, "Date").andCallFake ->
  new testContext._Date(time)
```